# Flex 4 fill color and gradient according to user requirement

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I want to design **fill property**(**Color and Gradient**) for a selected object(**Display Object ,UIComponent or Group**).
I've design a interface for  color but it's only works for fill color.
how i can design fill color and fill gradient simultaneously so user can fill color or gradient according to his/her requirement.

A single Object code is:- `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           implements="sharedData.IObjectProperty"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="120" height="70">



<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.graphics.GradientEntry;
        import mx.graphics.LinearGradient;
        import mx.graphics.SolidColor;


        private var _color:uint = 0xFFFFFF;
        private var _alpha:uint=1;

        private var _strokeColor:uint = 0x000000;
        private var _strokeAlpha:uint = 1;
        private var _strokeWeight:uint =1;


        [Bindable]
        public function get strokeColor():uint
        {
            return _strokeColor;

        }

        public function set strokeColor(Color:uint):void
        {
            _strokeColor = Color;

        }

        [Bindable]
        public function get strokeAlpha():uint
        {
            return _strokeAlpha;

        }
        public  function set strokeAlpha(Size:uint):void
        {
            _strokeAlpha = Size;
        }
        [Bindable]
        public function get strokeWeight():uint
        {

            return _strokeWeight;
        }
        public function set strokeWeight(Weight:uint):void
        {
            _strokeWeight = Weight;
        }

        /*property for color and alpha*/

        [Bindable]
        public function get ObjColor():uint
        {
            return _color;

        }
        public function set ObjColor(ColorObj:uint):void
        {
            _color = ColorObj;
        }

        [Bindable]
        public function get ObjAlpha():uint
        {
            return _alpha;

        }
        public function set ObjAlpha(AlphaObj:uint):void
        {  
            _alpha = AlphaObj;

        }



    ]]>
</fx:Script>


    <!--s:Path width="100%" height="100%" data="M 10 0 L 120 0 L 110 10 L 0 10 L 10 0 M 110 10 L 110 70 L 0 70 L 0 10 M 120 0 L 120 60 L 110 70">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#000033" alpha="1" 
                                weight="1" pixelHinting="true"/>
        </s:stroke>
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#FFFFFF" alpha="0.5"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Path-->

    <s:Path  width="100%" height="100%" data="M 10 0 L 130 0 L 120 10 L 0 10 L 10 0 M 0 10 L 0 70 L 120 70 L 120 10 M 120 70 L 130 60 L 130 0 L 120 10" id="iface">

        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke alpha="{strokeAlpha}" color="{strokeColor}" weight="{strokeWeight}"/>

        </s:stroke>

        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor alpha="{ObjAlpha}" color="{ObjColor}">

            </s:SolidColor>

        </s:fill>



    </s:Path>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Group>
`
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, so you should show us what you have already done. Then people can suggest suitable enhancements to add gradient fill option.

Comment: @LeeBurrows i've added a single file code . please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I am reading this correctly, you can do it one of two ways.

1) You can create the fill Objects within your `fx:Declarations` tags and set it manually within your AS3.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:SolidColor id="solid" />
    <s:LinearGradient id="grad" />
</fx:Declarations>  
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        if ( this ) {
            this.graphicsObjects.fill = solid;
        }
        else if ( that ) {
            this.graphicsObjects.fill = grad;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

2) You can use states. This is my preferred method for actions like this.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:SolidColor id="solid" />
    <s:LinearGradient id="grad" />
</fx:Declarations>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="solidFill"/> <!-- Will default to the first state in the array -->
    <s:State name="gradFill"/>
</s:States>
<s:Rect fill.solidFill="{this.solid}" fill.gradFill="{this.grad}"/>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
             this.currentState = "solidFill";
             this.currentState = "gradFill";
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

If you don't already know, `State`s allow you to define how an object will look and/or behave at certain points ("states"). You set the `currentState` to "gradFill" and the MXML knows to use `fill.gradFill` for the `Rect` object. It's simple and lets internal mechanisms handle the swapping. As an added benefit, you can take advantage of `Transition`s as well (see the LiveDocs) and even have multiple objects change in each state.

Either way will work, so it's really just up to you to decide how you want to handle it.

Comment: i've never use flex states.

Comment: how i can fill(gradient or solid color) an uiComponent using state.

Comment: Going by your code, you're using a `Path`. So `<s:Path data="" fill="{this.solidFill}" fill.grad="{this.gradFill}"/>` or similar